# Running ASP.net V5 in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to run code sample from https://github.com/aspnet/home in the VSCode in Windows 7 OS. I successfully launched the website but it errors out

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

MissingMethodException: Method not found:'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Compilation.ILibraryExport Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager.GetLibraryExport(System.String)'.
```

Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService.GetApplicationReferences()

I tried upgrading the DNVM and tried listing the version available and did "dnu restore"

```
Active Version     Runtime Architecture Location                           Alia
                                                                       s
------ -------     ------- ------------ --------                           ----
 *    1.0.0-beta4 clr     x86          C:\Users\***\.dnx\runtimes d...
```

Please help fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I solved it by getting the latest dev build. So I'm guessing it's a bug in the current nuget package build. From the github page:

> DNVM has the concept of a stable and unstable feed. Stable defaults to NuGet.org while unstable defaults to our dev MyGet feed. So if you add -u or -unstable to any of the install or upgrade commands you will get our latest CI build of the DNX instead of the one last released on NuGet

Try running the below command and then launching the site again.

```
dnvm upgrade -u
```

Comment: your solution works perfectly fine. I am now able to launch my V5 website. Thanks.